# Connect Android USB Accessory when screen is off

Tags: android, usb, accessory

## Application Info

I've got an application that is able to communicate with a USB accessory when the screen is on.

The first thing I do, after installing the app, is turn the screen on and then plug in the USB accessory. I get the message "Open  when this USB accessory is connected?". Additionally, there is a checkbox that says "Use by default for this USB accessory". I click the checkbox and press OK.[1]

Now, whenever I plug in the USB accessory, my application pops to the foreground. The reason this happens is because I have the following in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter" />
```

After this happens, I then call enable() that is defined here:

```
public boolean enable() {
    UsbManager deviceManager = null;
    UsbAccessory[] accessories = null;
    UsbAccessory accessory = null;

    deviceManager = (UsbManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

    accessories = deviceManager.getAccessoryList();
    accessory = accessories[0];
    if (accessory == null) {
        return false;
    }

    logDRemote("Accessory is " + accessory);
    // If we have permission to access the accessory,
    if (deviceManager.hasPermission(accessory)) {
        parcelFileDescriptor = deviceManager
                .openAccessory(accessory);

        if (parcelFileDescriptor != null) {
            logDRemote("descriptor is not null");

            if(parcelFileDescriptor == null) {
                logDRemote("parcelFileDescriptor == null");
                return false;
            }

            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());

            if(outputStream == null) {
                logDRemote( "outputStream == null");
                return false;
            }

            logDRemote("outputStream open");

            byte[] data = new byte[2];
            data[0] = (byte) APP_CONNECT;
            data[1] = 0;
            try {
                outputStream.write(data);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logDRemote("Could not open accessory");
                closeAccessory();
                return RETURN_CODES.FILE_DESCRIPTOR_WOULD_NOT_OPEN;
            }

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I call this after the activity pops to the foreground, I call this function and it returns `true`, showing that the USB device is properly communicating.

## Failure with swipe up screen

The problem is, if I have my screen off without a PIN but I have to swipe up to unlock the phone, the following happens:

- When I plug in the USB accessory, the screen turns on and says "swipe up"
- My activity does not pop up until after I swipe up on the screen
- If I never swipe on on the screen and try calling enable(), I get a failure at "Could not open accessory"

  - That is, the device is able to open properly, and the permissions exist. But it just can't actually write to the accessory when it tries.

## Fix for swipe up screen failure

I found a way to fix this first issue. What I was able to do is open up the activity whenever I detect that a USB charger is present[3]. Now the following happens:

- I start by installing the application with the USB unplugged
- I turn off the screen
- I plug in the USB device
- The activity pops up
- A second activity pops up. I believe that second activity popping up is the Android system opening the popup as a result of the USB attach event[2]
- I call enable(), and the write succeeds.

## Failure with pin lock

However, this fix does not work when I have a pin set on the phone. Now the following happens:

- I start by installing the application with the USB unplugged.
- I turn off the screen
- I plug in the USB device
- The activity pops up
- A second activity does *not* pop up
- I try calling enable(), and the write fails.

## The Final Question

How do I connect to a USB device when my Android phone is off and has a pin set? I have root, if that helps.

## Footnotes

1. As an aside, this writes to `/data/system/users/0/usb_device_manager.xml`, as seen in the source here: http://androidxref.com/7.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/usb/java/com/android/server/usb/UsbSettingsManager.java#mSettingsFile
2. http://androidxref.com/7.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/usb/java/com/android/server/usb/UsbSettingsManager.java#775
3. I'm putting the following in onCreate of the activity, so that it can show up while the screen is off:

-

```
  final Window win= getWindow();
    win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: Hey, I am trying to do something similar. did you ever solve this?

Comment: I was never able to unfortunately :/

Comment: I created a hidden boot activity that gets created when the USB accessory is attached. in onCreate I open the accessory and initialize the accessory and ensure that I can write to it. then I launch another activity and finish() the boot activity. When the pin is set and the screen is off, the other activity never launches but at least the accessory is initialized.